# Reseting "Thread Context"

Tags: jmeter

I would like to know if it is possible to reset the thread context (all of its variables) at the begining of a new iteration.

The problem that I am having is that the thread keeps all the variables (and its values) from its previous iterations and sometimes it things can get messy.

If I am not mistaken, on VisualStudio Performance tests you can specify the percentage of "new users" to indicate how many VirtualUsers are going to have its contexts reseted on their next test iteration.

Do we have something similar native on JMeter or do we need to write some code to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of variables you create and how you use them.

For ex:

- `Regular Expression Extractor`

[image]

Here It creates a variable `regex.var` and if the response matches the expression it will have some value assigned to it. If the next iteration does not match the expression, It will still keep the previous iteration value. To avoid this problem, assign a default value or check the 'Use empty default value'. so that every iteration will basically reset the value.

- `User Designed Variables` - Each and every thread will have its own copy of the variable and threads could be modifying its variable value throughout the entire duration of the test. If you want that to be reset for every iteration, it is completely your responsibility.

I think this could be helpful.

[JMeter - Understanding Variables Scope](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-understanding-the-scope-of-variables-sharing-among-threads-and-thread-groups/)

Comment: Hi vinz, thanks for your answer. I really need to delete all the variables and not only reset their values because for some RegularExpression/JSON Extractors I am using MatchNo as "-1" so it creates 'n' variables and they will keep storing values that are not going to be used. Furthermore, I believe that it may mess up some functions like and I also use them to select a random value from "${__V(extracted_item_${__Random(1,${extracted_item_matchNr},)})}".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you really want/need it, but you can remove all JMeter variables using JSR223 script with [remove method](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html):

```
for (Map.Entry entry : vars.entrySet()) {    
    vars.put(entry.getKey(), null);
}
```

Comment: Hi user7294900, thanks for your answer. I want to delete (not just to clear its values) ALL the variables that were created during one thread iteration, so, when this same thread starts a new iteration it will have no variables with empty values but instead, fresh variables will be created.